# Неправильное выделение памяти

Tags: c

Есть код, который считывает файл и выводит его на экран. Проблема в том, что появляется "мусор", который выводится вместе с полезной информацией. При том при первом вызове функции данной проблемы не наблюдается, только при повторном и следующих. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Притом иногда подобной проблемы не возникает.

```
 fseek(sd , 0 , SEEK_END);
   long size = ftell(sd);
   fseek(sd , 0 , SEEK_SET);
   char * buf = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) * size);                   
   fread (buf, 1, size, sd);
   puts (buf);
   free(buf);
   close(sd);
```

Comment: Проверяйте отладчиком значения переменных в контрольных точках.

Comment: @alexolut Посмотрел. Размер он считывает правильно, но как мне посмотреть buf на отладке я так и не понял. Там мешанина символов, из которой что-то понять не так просто.

Comment: `puts` должен получать нуль-терминированную строку. `buf` после чтения в `fread` скорее всего не такой. Ну и файл, надеюсь, текстовый у Вас.

Comment: Ваша программа только читает файл? Или пишет в него тоже? Полагаю, при записи файл не очищается, вот там и остаётся "мусор" от прежнего вывода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Есть другая ф-ия, которая записывает в данный файл. Обнуление последнего байта чарового массива, который записывается в файл, проблему не решает.

Comment: Покажите записывающую функцию. С какими ключами открывается файл, что и как пишется.

Answer (score 2):

В `malloc` выделяйте `size + 1` байт памяти и явно обнуляйте последний байт
(`buf[size] = 0;`).

Comment: Спасибо, данный вариант помог решить проблему с выводом. Но осталась другая. Если менять файл вручную, то "мусора" не выводится. А вот если воспользоваться другой функцией, которая дописывает текст в этот файл, то при выводе снова рандомно появляются левые символы(не всегда, раз через 2/3/4), притом в файле все чисто.

Comment: @hroftnya  Весь код и образец файла представьте в вопросе.

Comment: Там довольно много строчек. Закинул весь проект в архив. Комменты присутствуют, хотя не везде. Я только учусь, поэтому при чтении кода возможен легкий испанский стыд.
http://rgho.st/8vsXkYmgl

Comment: @hroftnya, `А вот если воспользоваться другой функцией, которая дописывает текст в этот файл` -- это вы о функции `zapisf()`? По крайней мере делать return, не закрыв открытые в ней файлы не стоит. И всюду надо поправить выделение-освобождение памяти. Если выделяете new, то освобождать надо delete, а free для malloc.
С файлом count.txt тоже не надо мудрить. Пишите в него тривиальным fprintf, а читайте fscanf и не нужен весь код со строкой, fread, atoi и т.п.

Comment: Честно говоря, я бы вообще не мудрил с дозаписью в файл. Всегда открывал на запись и писал старое содержимое (оно у вас есть) + новую строку. И проще всего добавления писать вызовом fprintf -- сразу новый номер дела, его текст и все \n

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Про free для malloc как-то совсем не подумал, да и с каунтом надо будет разобраться. Попробую завтра с этим всем разобраться, надеюсь заработает.

Comment: @hroftnya, если в файле всё хорошо, это лишь означает, что у вас гонка за реальные данные. Поскольку запись кэшируется, то вы можете читать "за границами" файла. Хотя это всего лишь версия, я всё же рекомендую использовать `fflush()` или подобные функции после каждой записи. А вообще с файлами надо работать через `mmap()`.